# Jest mock unable to iterate over async interable

Tags: node.js, jestjs, iterator

I'm using the `google-cloud/compute` library in my nodejs application to get the details of persistent disks in my account.

```
const { DisksClient } = require("@google-cloud/compute").v1;

module.exports = () => {
    const getAllDisks = async (credential, project) => {

        const allDisks = [];

        const client = computeClient({ credentials });
        const aggregatedList = client.aggregatedListAsync({ project });

        for await (const [zone, disksScoped] of aggregatedList){
            allDisks.push([zone, disksScoped]);
        }

        return { allDisks };
    }

    return { getAllDisks };
};
```

So far so good.

I am trying to make a unit test for this and have been running into an issue mocking the `aggregatedListAsync` method.

```
const { DisksClient } = require("@google-cloud/compute").v1;
jest.mock("@google-cloud/compute");
const { getAllDisks } = require("../src/getAllDisks")();

const mockDisks = [
    [
        "regions/us-central1",
        {
            disks: [],
            ...
        }
    ]
]

const mockAsyncIterator = {
    [Symbol.asyncIterator]: function(){
        return mockDisks;
    }
}

describe("getAllDisks unit test", () => {
    describe("Given a successful call", () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            DisksClient.prototype.aggregatedListAsync.mockResolvedValue(mockAsyncIterator);
        });
        it("Should return disks", async () => {
            const result = await getAllDisks("creds", "projectid");
            const { allDisks } = result;
            expect(...)
        })
    });
});
```

An error thrown when testing indicates that `aggregatedList is not async iterable`.

The type definition for `aggregatedListAsync` is given as:

```
aggregatedListAsync(request?: protos.google.cloud.compute.v1.IAggregatedListDisksRequest, options?: CallOptions): AsyncIterable<[string, protos.google.cloud.compute.v1.IDisksScopedList]>;
```

so the for-await-of does successfully retrieve persistent disk resources in my project.

I noticed that using `.mockResolvedValue` actually returned a *promise* resolving to the async iterator.
However, when changed to `.mockReturnValue`, the error message is now `".for is not iterable"`.

I think the issue is due to format of my mock but.. still unsure as I haven't been able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an incompatibility with running jest and apple silicon.

Workaround was to run the tests in 64-bit shell.

i.e.

```
arch -86_64 zsh

npx jest ...
```